# maven https working without import certifcate into java trusstore

Tags: maven, https

i am using maven3.3, without any settings without import https's website's server certificate and root CA into java truststore. everything is working. how come??? I am expected https connection deny!
any hints will be more than welcome!

my maven3.3 is downloading artifacts successfully from  maven central repository https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

the server certificate(repo.maven.apache.org  ) is issued by DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA 
none of them are imported into java (which is used by maven)'s key store.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate `DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA` is an intermediate certificate which is signed by `DigiCert Global Root CA`. The latter is included in Java's default keystore (located in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security`). Use OpenSSL to show the certificate chain for `repo.maven.apache.org`:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect repo.maven.apache.org:443 < /dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

(Look for "Certificate chain".)

Use Java's keytool to show the list of trusted certificates in the default keystore:

```
keytool -list -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

You will notice a certificate with the alias `digicertglobalrootca` which is the above mentioned `DigiCert Global Root CA`.